# Is there a way not to expose a method to client side?

Tags: gwt, rpc

I’m using GWT 2.5, and RPC to exchange information between client and server.

I’m trying to define the interface that extends RemoteService and another one `CRUDService<T>` that has among others (CRUD methods) the following method:

```
public Class<T> getDtoType();
```

But this method is only intended to be user by the implementation, on the server side.

Is there a way not to expose this method to client side (transient method)?

Otherwise I’m getting an error, when I compile the project, saying `Class<T>` does not `implements Serializable` nor `IsSerializable`.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. Atleast not without hacking gwt-dev and rpc related code for service proxy generation.

```
1) SampleService extends RemoteService, CrudService<String>
2) SampleService extends CrudService<String> ( where CrudService extends RemoteService )
```

In both above scenarios Async Interface cribs first. If you fix it then GWT proxy generators crib about Serialization interface.

Comment: That's a pity, I really wanted to use the same interface in client and server side and in my perspective it make sense not to expose a certain method to client side (my perspective its the server who defines the contract (interface)), I remember in other technologies like blazeds where it can be defined the methods that are exposed to client side. I will think in a work around. Thanks you

Comment: Indeed. I had never thought about it along your premise till today. I am still undecided on who owns the contract server or client. GWT currently presumes its the client. Perhaps you can pitch this in a GWT discussion thread on G+ or Google Groups

Comment: I post a new discussion thread in google groups, you can follow here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/p4E5R8yKfpE